# How can multiple (dynamically sized) divs share 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I've got following html structure:

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="float:left; width:70%"><input /></div>
  <div style="float:left">element with unknown width</div>
  <div style="float:left; width=30%"><input /></div>
  <div style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

- (Requirement) The outer div should use 100% of the screen width
- (Requirement) The three inner divs should share these 100% among themselves
- (Requirement) The second div, between the two others, occupies an unknown quantity of space
- The two input fields should use up all the remaining space, but the first one shall receive 70% of the remainder, while the third one gets 30%

How can something like this be done?

Comment: if my calculation are right, the middle div occupy 0%, you have to do the math right, ex: 30%,30% and 40%. If you really want it to be dynamic with conditions, use javascript

Comment: Another `give me the code` question... Shhh

Comment: @Ibu What he means is that the second div will have an unknown width. regardless of the width of the second div, whatever space remains is shared by the first and third, 70% and 30% respectively.

however, you can't do this with CSS alone.

Comment: Well, the example code was just for illustration. I'm trying to assign the remaining space to the two divs with the ratio 70:30. To be clear, the center div won't change its size once it's set, but I don't know the size at this point and it might change based on different locales. So the "dynamic" in the title might have lead you astray. If javascript is indeed the only way to go here, then thanks for the hint.

Comment: @homework: well, in way it is, but no. Maybe you got the wrong impression, because the question has so many "requirements". Just to be clear, the html structure is not required as stated. The described "flow" of the layout is the goal, if there is another hmtl/css combination that solves the problem then I'm more than happy to hear it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Get per javascript the width of the second div and the width of your outer container. div1-width=(container-width - div2-width)*0.7. div2-width=(container-width - div2-width)*0.3. Then you can set the width of the two divs per javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RoToRa: Thanks for the tip. I guess this is the final solution for this problem:

Distribute 70:30

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:70%">
    <input style="width:100%"/>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:1px">
    <a style="white-space:nowrap">Some Text</a>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width=30%">
    <input style="width:100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution, where the first input field grabs all excess space, and the final input field has fixed width:

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:100%">
    <input style="width:100%"/>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:1px">
    <a style="white-space:nowrap">Some Text</a>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width=100px">
    <input style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is determining the width of the middle div?  As my rep score will atest I am not a very experienced developer, but I think this is the crux of your problem. If it litterally does not matter what the middle column's width is then a div ratio of 70%, 0%, 30% and 7%, 90%, 3%. are mathematically equivlent answers to your problem. So your solution could be as simple as:

```
<div style="width:100%">
   <div style="float:left; width:7%">Some elements here.</div>
   <div style="float:left; width:90%">Some more elements here.</div>
   <div style="float:left; width:3%">Even more elements here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, your right. There are numerous solutions to solve this problem pragmatically. I have to admit, it is more of an academic question at this point. I'm relatively new to CSS and encountered this problem in an app I'm currently developing. The requirement seemed so basic and common to me, that after an hour on google, I couldn't believe not finding an answer to it, so I posted it here... hopeful to be enlightened by a CSS guru :-) Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Tables are supposed to be evil, but they seem to solve the problem.
I'm still interested in a solution without javascript or tables, if anyone can find one...

Distribute remaining space with ratio 70:30

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%">
      <input style="width:100%"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>Some Text</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%">
      <input style="width:100%"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

First input field uses up all remaining space, while the last box has a fixed width:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100%">
      <input style="width:100%"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>Some Text</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100px">
      <input style="width:100px"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't have to use HTML tables to do "table layouts". Use CSS and the `display: table-*` properties: http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table