# Elements share 100% width CSS

Tags: css

I like to make a layout with multiple elements that share 100% width of the parent element.
Found already a solution: [how-can-multiple-dynamically-sized-divs-share-100-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571958/how-can-multiple-dynamically-sized-divs-share-100-width).
The problem is here i always need some wrapper elements like divs. Like to realize this
only with input, button elements and so on.

```
<form>
   <button style="width: 20px;"></button>
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="text"/>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code you're working on?

Answer (score 1):

input and button elements are inline elements.

Just add the `display: block` rule on them to make the `width: 100%` rule implicit.

block-level elements will inherit their parent's width by default and will be rendered one below the other.

For a form, you can use this kind of code:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input />
    <button />
</form>
```

CSS

```
form input,
form button{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I can display them as table-cell to get 100 % shared content but it does not work... They need to be embedded in a table-cell element. Thats what i like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want them to have a `100%` width, then you can use

```
min-width: 100%;
```

Comment: That`s not im looking for.