# children not occupying parent container's whole width

Tags: html, css

The inner children are not occupying the entire width of the parent container.

The HTML is:

```
  <div class="parent_cntr">
<div class="sub_parent_cntr cf">
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub_parent_cntr cf">
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 1</span>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 3</span>
    </div> -->
</div>
<div class="sub_parent_cntr cf">
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_cntr">
        <span>COL 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
   .parent_cntr{width: 100%; border: 1px solid;}
   .sub_parent_cntr{border: 1px solid;}
   .child_cntr{padding: 10px 1.5%; border: 1px solid red; float:left; width :30%}
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
     }

     .cf:after {
        clear: both;
      }
```

The js fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/K7gC5/2/
I am unable to get the reason for this space you can see in the screenshot.

Any help would be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has got to do with this line of CSS:

```
.child_cntr{
    padding: 10px 1.5%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width :30%
}
```

You use a width of 30% which means with 3 elements it spans only 90%. The 10% remaining is white space. Also the padding and the 1px border add extra size to the width in your case.

Unfortunately I can't provide a fix now because of lack of time. I'll get back to you asap.

## Update

Check this one out: it might just help you: [How can multiple (dynamically sized) divs share 100% width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571958/how-can-multiple-dynamically-sized-divs-share-100-width)

Answer (score 0):

I presume its something to do with the clearfix content attribute.

Here is a universal clearfix hack

```
/* slightly enhanced, universal clearfix hack */
.cf:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.cf { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .cf { height: 1%; }
.cf { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Also try changing the child width of the child value to 30.1%